# android Back button functionalit

Tags: android

I just need to know this. Since calling the finish() in the activity takes you to the previous activity, when you press the Back button it actually **finishes** the current activity and takes you to the previous activity?

Comment: check this out: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user presses the back button on the current activity it  is popped from the activity stack and destroyed and the previous activity is resumed with its re-stored state.

Read [Tasks and Backstack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for a more detailed information. It is essential that you understand this concept thoroughly.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This would be true if you haven't gotten rid of the activity by say calling `finish()` on your previous activity. You also can change the functionality by calling

```
@Override   
public void onBackPressed() {    
// do something on back.

return;
}
```